# Redirect Users Based on Server Traffic

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, redirect

I have a PHP script that finds out the number of users on each of my servers and inputs it into a MySQL database. I want the user to be redirected to the page with the least users on it, defined by the MySQL database.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance,
Callum

Comment: How can this be done?  By writing the code to do it.  But seriously, this is a very non-trivial problem with lots of edge-cases to worry about.  I'd suggest instead reading about [Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing), [An O'Reilly Article on Load Balancing](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/09/26/load.html?page=1), and more that you can find via google...

Comment: It seems like you have everything necessary and the right solution idea. Read out that database, check for threshold, order by server with least load, issue a redirect header. - Or what have you tried, did you run into a specific problem, or do you suspect a stumbling block in your approach?

Comment: @Callum Whyte - there are some many reliable and easy to configure load balancing hardware, spent the $$$, your logic to me has a big problem, `you are trying to reduce load by just creating a load on database checking + complex calculation + script execution `

Comment: @Callum Whyte - how about use of memcache ? Where you can store different web pages using different memcache key, and each specific user able to get the data from memcache based on a match memcache key

Comment: @Callum Whyte - you probably should change the question to avoid `Server Traffic` cause it make everyone (at least me) thinking is related to load balancing

Comment: @Callum White: Can I ask what you're trying to do?  Are you trying to fall back on a static HTML cache of the site to prevent the `/. effect`?  Or is there something else you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query on your db that sorts on the number of users.

```
SELECT ServerColumn FROM Table ORDER BY NumberOfUsersColumn ASC;
```

That would retrieve the servers ordered by their serverload (as defined in your db).

As for the redirection part you can take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

And use the "Location" header.

Comment: This answer will work based on the limited description in the question.  However using MySQL for load balancing sounds like smelly code to me...  There are many better methods available.